# Java Message Object Enum Spring integration Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I have a class

```
public enum A{
   LOAN1,
   LOAN2
}
```

I build my message object as below:-

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
public Message handle(Message<?> message){

    Message<String> message1 = (Message<String>);

    MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
                .setHeader("ID", person.getID())
                .setHeader("AType",A.LOAN1)
                .build();

    logger.info("Enriched Header with 2nd Attribute-->> "+message1.getHeaders().get("AType"));

    return message1;
}
```

The Above Code works fine. Prints everything fine.

Now in my other Spring Boot App which consumes message1 from KafkaTopic

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT)
public Message handle2(Message<?> message){

    A atype = (A) message.getHeaders().get("AType");
    logger.info("RECEIVED ENUM data is-->> "+atype);
}
```

This above part errors out. `NonTrustedHeaderType`

Not clear on Enum concepts wrt Spring Kafka Headers as much as I need to be. But I am learning. Much Appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NonTrustedHeaderType` means that you are missing to trust to the package where your `Enum` lives.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#headers):

> By default, the mapper will only deserialize classes in `java.lang` and `java.util`. You can trust other (or all) packages by adding trusted packages using the `addTrustedPackages` method. If you are receiving messages from untrusted sources, you may wish to add just those packages that you trust. To trust all packages use `mapper.addTrustedPackages("*")`.

Also there is an appropriate configuration property from the [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kafka-extra-props) perspective:

> spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=com.example,org.acme

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add it to trusted header names. For example, see [spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headerMapperBeanName](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Fishtown.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_apache_kafka_binder) binder property to point to an instance of the `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` bean.